# How to enable snapping when moving multiple features at once?

Tags: qgis, snapping, digitizing

Is there a way to enable snapping when moving two or more features at once?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible (yet) doing it natively in QGIS. I think the closest tool available is the **move** plugin:

> Move all selected objects from point to point with snap

You can download this from the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```